# how to change appbar color when button tap from other screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dart-null-safety, flutter-appbar, flutter-sliverappbar

I'm using *BottomNavigationBar* and *AppBar* in *HomeScreen* in which I'm using two screens *A and B* ,
now I want to *change AppBar background color* when tapping a TextButton from B screen

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you;ve tried so far?

Comment: use state-management packages to achieve this eg. package-name :  get

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the solution:

1.Take the AppBar background color in a variable(ex-color) of type color and pass this color as a constructor to new screen(suppose B).

2.Now bind the onclick of textbutton of screen B to a function inside setState that changes color of variable color by changing it's content dynamically at wherever it's getting used.

Comment: I have tried to pass color in constructor like this ```UserNetworkPage(app_bar_color:app_bar_color)``` and changed color using setstate like this ```widget.app_bar_color=Color(0xffA4E5E1)``` but it doesn't work

Comment: Please try this approach app_bar_color=Color(0xffA4E5E1) and import your UserNetworkPage page.